# Best way to create a JSON schema?

Tags: c#, json

I need to post a request to a REST api that requires the JSON to be formatted in a very particular way:

Below is a sample post of the JSON that the API expects. How can I model my request to be in this particular model.

I am using JSON.NET c# library.

JSON model:

```
{
    "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericEntityData, Asi.Contracts",
    "Properties": {
        "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyDataCollection, Asi.Contracts",
        "$values": [
            {
                "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
                "Name": "ACTIVITY_TYPE",
                "Value": "ONLINEAPP"
            },
            {
                "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
                "Name": "PartyId",
                "Value": "22708"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to use "Paste Special" function in Visual Studio. it can be found under Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as classes.

it will create classes like below.

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Properties Properties { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Values[] values { get; set; }
}

public class Values
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```